# Logic App Http POST request UnsupportedMediaType error

Tags: http, http-headers, azure-logic-apps, content-type

I am getting the following error in my logic app:

`{ "type": "https://errors-api.cloud.com/common/unsupportedMediaType", "detail": "Content type '' not supported", "parameters": null }`
The following is my set up:

[image]

This works in Postman.
[image]

However, I noticed that in the Logic App if I add in a text in the Body section. For example "body". It works fine
[image]

The Body is not needed in the Postman so it's confusing to me why it needed in Logic app. Anyone come across similar issue?

Comment: I would focus more on the `unsupportedMediaType` error, rather than the body. The error says that the `Content type is ''`. What is the trigger?

Comment: The trigger is "When a HTTP request is received". I am just testing this right now. I do not get the `content type is ' '` error when there is something in the body

Answer (score 0):

Issue is with content-type in your case. I have tried to reproduce issue from my side, but I did not get any error. I have found similar issue like you in [link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/1b88c2e3-6816-49b4-b60a-b585d2ebe90c/logic-apps-unsupported-media-type-at-launching-a-pipeline-endpoint?forum=azurelogicapps)

Also, can you add Accept as shown below in header request,

```
Accept:*/*
```

1. I have created logic app as shown below,
   [image]
2. In Get Bearer Token, getting access token from authentication url,
   [image]
3. Using access token from Get bearer token getting data from api as shown below,
   [image]
4. The logic app ran successfully,
   [image]